# Interfacing PIC24E with ICD3

Tags: pic, pic24

I am trying to connect ICD-3 to PIC24E micro-controller, and I'm finding difficulty in detecting the device. All the recommendations, as in ICD-3 interface document has been ensured, and still on sending command via PRD line of ICD-3, the device is showing an error of Target ID not detected. The MCLR line is pulled by a 10kOhm resister as well. Is there anything else I have to ensure during communication and have I missed something in between. I have attached the ICD-3 document link as well. (https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/DS-51765C.pdf).

Comment: Have you switched on Vdd? Either on your board or in your tool.

Comment: Yes it was connected.